# Game of Bots A and B

Tags: algorithms

There are two kind of bots in the game BOT A and BOT B. Both are designed so as to move only in one direction in a 1-D array. Bot A can move towards left whereas bot B is constrained to move rightwards. Both are constrained to move only to the empty elements and one cannot jump over another bot. Now, a particular state of array can be represented with a string of A,B and # where A/B represents that BOT of kind A/B is sitting there and # represents an empty space.

For example: AA###B, represents an arena of length 5, where A sits at first two places, then three empty places and bot of kind B at last place. Here, B can be atmost 3 postitions leftwards and that too when both A do not move.

Now given 2 strings which consists of A,B and # representing a particular state we need to tell if 2nd state could be obtained from 1st one or not.

EXAMPLE :

#A#B#B#

A###B#B

Then here answer is "Yes" as A bot can move one unit leftwards and both bot B can move one unit right wards to get the desired state.

Whereas in

#A#B#

#B#A#

Answer is "No"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two conditions must hold:

1) After removing the #'s, we should get the same strings.

2) Let $a_i$ and $a_i^{'}$ denote, respectively, the number of $A$'s with coordinate less than or equal to $i$ in the initial and final configuration. Then for every $1 \leq i \leq L$ we need to have $a_i^{'} \leq a_i$, where $L$ is the length of the array. Analogously for the $B$'s we need $b_i^{'} \geq b_i$.